# Create git Branch/Tag via ANT script

Tags: git, ant, git-branch

I'um using ANT scripts to build jar files with version. Is there an oportunity to also create a tag/branch in the git repository in the ANT script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**rimerosolutions/ant-git-tasks**](https://github.com/rimerosolutions/ant-git-tasks) for common git tasks in ant.

That include creating a branch:

```
<git:git directory="repositoryCloneFolder" verbose="true" settingsRef="git.testing">
 <git:clone uri="https://github.com/rimerosolutions/playground-repo.git"/>
 <git:checkout branchName="dummyBranch" createBranch="true"/>
</git:git>
```

Or [creating a tag](https://github.com/rimerosolutions/ant-git-tasks/blob/79826f93177ba18cd9506d8946f219519e27d427/src/main/java/com/rimerosolutions/ant/git/tasks/TagTask.java#L26-L40):

```
<git:git directory="${testLocalRepo}" verbose="true">
 <git:tag name="${dummy.tag.name}"/>
</git:git>
```

Comment: would be Commit,Tag,Push the right for me?
I want to commit than create the jar files and tag the commit, afterwards I want all In sync with the remote branch.

Comment: @user2071938 You generally don't commit and tag binary files in a git repo, only source files.

Comment: sure, my ant file so far creates executable jar files, including all depending libraries, this ant file creates a file "myapp-1.5.0.jar", now I want a connection to my source, so I want to tag the current commit with "v1.5.0"

Comment: As long as the jar itself is not committed, you can tag the commit indeed

Comment: is there a way to commit only if changes are made? If I run my current ant file 5-times, I get 5 commits.

Comment: @user2071938 This applies to a git repo: any commit will fail if there is no change. You need changes added to the index for a commit to take place.

Comment: <git:git directory="/home/bf/pro/workspace/XXTestJava/src" verbose="true" settingsRef="ref.git">
   <git:commit/> 
</git:git>

Any time I execute this, without any changes(checked with 'git status') I get a new commit!